# Refactoring of TextField/TextFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Can we refactor `TextField/TextFormField` in Flutter without rebuilding the Widget?
I tried to refactor the `TextField` Widget for a form that I have created to collect some data. But, when I dismiss my keyboard, the data is losing because the widget is rebuilding. Is there any way to fix it? Pls, Let me know...

> See the code below of the Refactored TextField

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ContentInputWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContentInputWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.controller,
    this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Content Input Widget Rebuild');
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: text,
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      controller: controller,
      keyboardType: keyboardType,
      maxLines: null,
    );
  }
}
```

I've used `Provider` and `Consumer` to get the data from the text field. And I got it by using a Providers Model Class

> See below

```
class ContentUpdater extends ChangeNotifier {
  String description = 'Description comes here';
  String name = 'Name';
  String prayerRequest = 'Request Comes here';
  String postDate = '01-01-2022';

  void updatePoster(
    String nameText,
    String descriptionText,
    String prayerReqText,
    String postDtText,
  ) {
    name = nameText;
    description = descriptionText;
    prayerRequest = prayerReqText;
    postDate = postDtText;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

> Called a Function to Update Content using `Provider`

```
() { Provider.of<ContentUpdater>(context, listen: false)
     .updatePoster(
     nameController.text.toString(),
     descriptionController.text.toString(),
     requestController.text.toString(),
     dateController.text.toString(),
     );
   }
```

This all works well. But the problem comes if we dismiss the keyboard by clicking the back button, the content disappears from the `TextField` ...

> Is there any way to do without using a `StateFulWidget`

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your TextFieldController using [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) (useTextEditingController). This will make it so the state of the TextEditingController isn't lost on rebuilds.

```
TextEditingController controller = useTextEditingController();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a long time ago. I don't remember exactly how I made it work, but you could try adding a `onChanged` function to your TextField and save the data before the re-build clears the text.

```
final String myText; 

void _onChanged() {
  if (controller.text != null && controller.text != "") {
    myText = controller.text;
  }
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Content Input Widget Rebuild');
    return TextField(
      onChanged: _onChanged,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: text,
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      controller: controller,
      keyboardType: keyboardType,
      maxLines: null,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably there because the controller is inside the stateless widget. When the state is changed, controller dies and gets rebuilt. Try wrapping widget inside a stateful widget and maybe it'll solve your issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ContentInputWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContentInputWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.controller,
    this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  State<ContentInputWidget> createState() => _ContentInputWidgetState();
}

class _ContentInputWidgetState extends State<ContentInputWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Content Input Widget Rebuild');
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: widget.text,
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      controller: widget.controller,
      keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
      maxLines: null,
    );
  }
}
```